# need subroutine batch file to ask to prompt to copy each individual file in a folder but it stays on a continuous loop

Tags: batch-file

need subroutine batch file to ask to prompt to copy each individual file in a folder but it stays on a continuous loop

here is the script
@echo off
echo.
echo The time is %time% on %date%.

```
echo.               
echo.Backup Starting...                         
echo.       
echo Checking if the source folder exists...    
echo.
if exist "%C:\Users\Lee\Project\%" (                REM checks if the source folder exists
set formerDir=%cd%                      REM sets the former directory
echo source folder exists.                  
) else (                            REM if the source folder doesnt exist user is notified                              
echo it doesn't exist                       
)


echo.
echo Checking if the Backup folder exists...
echo.
if exist "%C:\Users\Lee\Backup\%" (             REM checks if the backup folder exists
set formerDir=%cd%                      REM sets the former directory
echo Backup folder exists.                      
) else (                            REM if the backup folder doesnt exist user is notified
echo Backup folder doesn't exist.
echo.
echo Creating Backup folder...
md%C:\Users\Lee\Backup\%                    REM backup folder is created
echo.
echo Folder has been created.                   REM user is notified
)
```

:Subroutine                               REM the subroutine
    echo.
    cd %C:\Users\Lee\Project%
    for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
    set /p p="Do you want to copy this file(Y/N)?"              REM user is asked if they want to copy the file 
    echo.
    echo %p%
    if "%p%" == "y" (                           REM is the user replies yes the file is copied to the backup folder
    echo.
    xcopy /y C:\Users\Lee\Project C:\Users\Lee\Backup
    attrib +r "C:\Users\Lee\Backup" 
    echo.
    echo File has been copied.
    ) else (
    echo.
    echo Skipped
    echo.
    )

```
call :Subroutine
echo.
echo Backup Complete!
echo.
echo Press enter to exit.
pause >nul                              REM results are paused on screen for the user
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch starts at a strange place. The very beginning. It has no concept of blocks in the same sense as Pascal or Delphi.

Consequently, when your routine has finished, it proceeds to the next statement, which is `call :subroutine` so it runs that until finished, and proceeds to the next statement which is `call :subroutine`....

Move your main routine block,

```
call :Subroutine
...
pause >nul
exit
```

to the start of the file, and all will be sweetness and light.

If you're feeling adventurous, you could insert

```
@echo off
```

as the very first line. This would suppress the echoing of each statement before it is executed.

Good practice tip: Add a line

```
goto :EOF
```

automatically at the end of each subroutine. This will cause execution of the subroutine to terminate as the destination `:EOF` - **WITH** the colon is understood to be `End-Of-File`. It's not absolutely necessary in the current case, but since batch simply charges through labels (it doesn't recognise labels as 'end of block') if you follow Mr. Pavlov and pop the `GOTO` in automatically, you won't suffer from problems caused by flow-through from a previous routine.

Comment: that was just the subroutine at the bottom of the script the rest of the script is as follows

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make a `call` while you're already in a `FOR` loop. You just have to include all your code in the `FOR` loop and after last file it will automatically go out of the loop.

```
@echo off
cd %C:\Users\Lee\Project%
for /r %%i in (*) do (echo %%i
                   set /p p="Do you want to copy this file(Y/N)?"
                   echo.
                   echo %p% 
                   if "%p%" == "y" (
                                    echo.
                                    xcopy /y C:\Users\Lee\Project C:\Users\Lee\Backup
                                    attrib +r "C:\Users\Lee\Backup"
                                    echo.
                                    echo File has been copied. ) else ( echo. echo Skipped
                                    echo.)))

echo. echo Backup Complete!
echo. 
echo Press enter to exit.
pause >nul
```

Comment: as soon as i add this code the batch just closes as soon as i open it is there a pause missing somewere maybe?

Comment: Try it again there was a missing ")"

Comment: also if i open it from cmd itself i get an error saying <do was unexpected at this time

Comment: I'm sleeping... try again the "(" wad before the `do`

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%f in ("c:\wherever\source\*.*") do (
    choice /c yn /m "copy file [%%~nxf]? "
    if errorlevel 2 (
        echo ... skipped
    ) else (
        echo copy "%%~ff" "c:\wherever\target"
    )
)
```